# If no express-cookie timeout is set, is there a defaulted timeout as a preset?

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, express-session

With express session, if you do not specify a max timeout example:

```
cookie: { maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000 * 30)) })
```

is there a default time that is preset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right there in the [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session), man:

"Settings object for the session ID cookie. The default value is `{ path: '/', httpOnly: true, secure: false, maxAge: null }`."